# error message not appearing though there is no error and put exit sub before error hadeler statment in vba

Tags: excel, error-handling, vba

I have been figuring out how to pop up msg box if there is error. I have below code but this code does not jump to error handler if there is error and Exit the sub.

```
Sub Validate_Region()

Dim str_DEPARTMENT_NAME As String

On Error GoTo Reion_Error

    If Left(Range("M4"), 2) = "As" Then
    str_DEPARTMENT_NAME = "India"
    ElseIf Left(Range("M4"), 2) = "ME" Then
    str_DEPARTMENT_NAME = "Middle East"
    End If
    'Get value of region selected in Master File
    str_regionvalue = Workbooks("Master Report").Sheets("Home").Range("T8")

    If str_regionvalue = str_DEPARTMENT_NAME Then
    MsgBox ("You have selected " & str_regionvalue & " region"), vbInformation

    End If
Exit Sub

Reion_Error:
    MsgBox ("Please select the correct Region.") & vbNewLine & vbNewLine & ("You have selected " & str_regionvalue & " region" & " In Home Sheet of Master Report and pulled the data for " & str_DEPARTMENT_NAME & " region"), vbCritical
    ActiveWorkbook.Close

End Sub
```

Comment: Are you seeing an error?  On what line?

Comment: Hi Tim, There is no any error. It just spiking code if there is error but does not jump on the Error Handler msg.

Comment: Check your error settings under tools >> options in the Vb editor.  Make sure it's not set to "break on all errors"

Answer (score 0):

Check your syntax, you have quite a few unnecessary brackets and commas in your msgbox statements. Try something like:

```
returnval = MsgBox ("Put message here" , vbInformation)
```

OR

```
MsgBox "another message " & vbnewline & "some more message", vbcritical
```

---

The code looks fine and compiles now but I think your error may be elsewhere. Possibly in:

```
str_regionvalue = Workbooks("Master report").Sheets("Home").Range("T8")
```

I'd suggest:

1. Leave the 'exit sub' in. It's correct.
2. Add 'Option Explicit' to the top of the code - it will force you to declare all variables (str_regionvalue isn't declared)
3. Set your Under Tools >> Options in the VB Editor: to 'Break on Unhandled Errors'.
4. Put in a breakpoint (Debug >> Add Watch) at the top of the code and run through it step by step using Debug >> Step Into.

Comment: Thank you so much for the reply @LeasMaps. I tried the above code but it is not working. If I skip the "Exit Sub" line in code then code execute the msg box if there is error perfectly. and If there is no error then code still throwing the Error Msg Box which should be skip.

Comment: In other case if I put "Exit Sub" the code does not jump to Error Handler if there is error and run till "Exit sub" only.

Comment: Hi Swapnil - the code looks fine and compiles now but I think your error may be elsewhere. Possibly in:
     str_regionvalue = Workbooks("Master Report").Sheets("Home").Range("T8")
??
I'd suggest:
1. Leave the 'exit sub' in. It's correct.
2. Add 'Option Explicit' to the top of the code - it will force you to declare all variables (str_regionvalue isn't declared)
3. Put in a breakpoint at the top of the code and run through it step by step using

Answer (score 0):

I just copy/pasted your code and it works well for me:

[image: error raised!]

I don't know from where this sub is called and what type of variable is used on `str_regionvalue` (seems like Variant)

So what can you do with this:

1. Get rid of `Exit Sub` on line #19.
2. Put Err.Number check in your error handler:

`Reion_Error:
    If Err.Number <> 0 Then
       MsgBox ("Please select the correct Region.") & vbNewLine & vbNewLine & ("You have selected " & str_regionvalue & " region" & " In Home Sheet of Master Report and pulled the data for " & str_DEPARTMENT_NAME & " region"), vbCritical
      'by the way, you can try to set ActiveWorkbook.Saved to True, to get rid from pop-ups on Close
       ActiveWorkbook.Close
    End If`

3. Try to look for error number thru debugging (`debug.print err.number` or place some `stop`'s to do this manually). Or add `err.number` to Watches and check `Break when value changes` so you can track where error raised and cleared (if raised).

[Err object](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/gg251525.aspx)

P.S. You got some ridiculous MsgBoxes, if you really like parentheses, use them like this:

```
    Call MsgBox("Please select the correct Region." & vbNewLine & vbNewLine  & _           
            "You have selected " & str_regionvalue & " region" & " In Home Sheet of Master Report and pulled the data for " & str_DEPARTMENT_NAME & " region", vbCritical)
```

Comment: Hi, can you send me the code which you have. I tried the above option but still doesn't work.  If I skip the "Exit Sub" line in code then code execute the msg box if there is error perfectly. and If there is no error then code still throwing the Error Msg Box which should be skip.  
In other case if I put "Exit Sub" the code does not jump to Error Handler if there is error and run till "Exit sub" only.

Comment: I just put you code in fresh new workbook and bound it to 'Worksheet_Change' event and because there's no sheet named "Home" and no workbook named "Master Report" I got 100% error.

Comment: And I dont know what "Error" MsgBox you get, that one, who raised from error handler when err.number not equal 0? And dont forget close your 'on error' statements with 'on error goto 0'!

Comment: Just to have clarification that the "Error Msg Box" I am referring here is a msg box that should appear when there is error. As per my code the error msg appearing though there is no error. If I skip adding "Exit Sub". If I add that the code stop till "Exit Sub" line and don't jump to Error handler though there is error.

Comment: Looks like you want Error when str_regionvalue <> str_DEPARTMENT_NAME, am I right? Because you look for correct Region, and when str_regionvalue <> str_DEPARTMENT_NAME its obviously, that there's no error, so you need raise one by yourself with err.raise if str_regionvalue <> str_DEPARTMENT_NAME

Comment: If you skip adding "Exit Sub" you messagebox would pop-up only when Err.Number <> 0, if you really add check for error number msgbox cannot appear if there is no error! And if you have "Exit Sub" code stops because you didn't deal with error, so exiting sub with error is not an option! Sorry, I really trying to get in your problem but seems like i failed.

Comment: Haha, than just add `Else` statement to your `If str_regionvalue = str_DEPARTMENT_NAME Then` check and place under `else` call for `Err.Raise` method, so you can raise error by yourself!

Comment: Hummm... that would work for me. But just wanted to check why the error handler not working. As that I can be refer in the future. By the way thank yo so much.

Comment: As I described, he works well. Your problem in that - you dont really know, what you want, you expect error when no error is possible to get, like meet some aliens in your house, when you just back home. It's OK that your strings isn't equal, there's no error for VBA, so if you really need one - create it! And I'm glad if we dealt with your problem (:

Comment: Thanks for support and information. that what I wanted to know how VBA does work for error handling. I used the IF statement as you suggested and it's working fine now. Thanks again and Have a great day:)

Answer (score 0):

Under Tools >> Options in the VB Editor: on the General tab make sure you don't have "Error trapping" set to "Break on all errors"

[image]